# Entity Framework Core 2.0, migrations for both SQL Server and Postgres?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework Core 2.0, how can I in the same solution keep migrations for both Microsoft SQL Server and Postgres if my application needs to be able to target both types? In my case if running on MacOS I want to use Postgres, and if running on Windows I want to use SQL Server. Before setup of DataContext we determine platform using calls to "RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(..)" and extract the appropriate connection string.

Currently the solution is separated into one ASP.NET Core project and one "Data" project which keeps the DataContext and migrations for SQL Server only.

My attempts, that have failed, have so far been:

1. Create separate projects for migrations, one for the SQL Server migrations and one for the Postgres migrations. Then run "ef migrations add ..." with the "-p" parameter pointing to the migrations project I want to use. This is done in conjunction with call to either ".UseNpgsql(connectionString, o => o.MigrationsAssembly(..)" or ".UseSqlServer(connectionString, o => o.MigrationsAssembly(..)". This fails with the tooling complaining that there is no DataContext found.
2. Same as "1." but we also add a class implementing  "IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<..>" in each of the migrations projects. This fails with the tooling complaining that there is no DataContext found.
3. Keep SQL Server migrations in the same project as the DataContext. Invoke "ef migrations add .." with the "-o" parameter specifying another output folder for the migrations for Postgres. This works for the SQL Server migrations, but fails for the Postgres migrations by way of that it does not like if a migration exists in the same project with the same name (even if it's in another folder), and also the migrations are generated for SQL Server and not for Postgres, even if they are put in the specified folder.

Is this a currently not supported scenario and we should stick with Postgres on all platforms? (which does work).

Comment: I just wrote [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers) on this very subject! Let me know what's missing.

Comment: HI @NeoDarque, when i try to migrate from ms sql to postgresql i also got the error no DataContext found, to solve the error i create dbcontext to the postgre migration project. it is strange that referencing dbcontext is not working.

Comment: EF Core 2.0 is completely out of support since 2018 and lacked far too many basic features. As the posted answer shows, there's a documentation page dedicated to [Migrations with Multiple Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: Please post your code outside the question text and include the actual error messages and actual commands. Right now it's very hard to understand what you actually tried or what went wrong. Talking about `DataContext` instead of `DbContext` adds to the confusion. Did you try to derive from DbContext or is that a typo? Did you run `dotnet ef migrations` in the *correct* folder?  Did you specify the correct projects?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is officially supported. See [Migrations with Multiple Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers).

You should specify separate assembly and a connection string for each provider like this:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(
            (hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

                // Set the active provider via configuration
                var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                var provider = configuration.GetValue("Provider", "SqlServer");

                services.AddDbContext<BlogContext>(
                    options => _ = provider switch
                    {
                        "Sqlite" => options.UseSqlite(
                            configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection"),
                            x => x.MigrationsAssembly("SqliteMigrations")),

                        "SqlServer" => options.UseSqlServer(
                            configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnection"),
                            x => x.MigrationsAssembly("SqlServerMigrations")),

                        _ => throw new Exception($"Unsupported provider: {provider}")
                    });
            });
```

Then you could specify a provider when creating migrations.

`dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration --project ../SqliteMigrations -- --provider Sqlite`

Comment: Turbcool, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @KiranShahi that's not the case here. A link to the official docs that explain how to handle the exact question step by step is useful in itself and very stable. You can argue that this should be a comment because we don't know enough to give any better answer yet. It's highly likely though that the OP will find the solution in the step-by-step guide